# Why does KeyChar for Delete return the same as for Period?

Tags: c#, .net

I am catching a KeyPress-Event to check for certain kinds of allowed values. To be able to delete I am using following code before the actual check

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Delete || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
{
   return;
}
...actual check for only digits or whatever
```

The problem is that e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Delete is also true when I hit the period on my keyboard.

How can this be? And what could I do about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation on the **Keys** enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx):

> The Keys class contains constants for processing keyboard input. The members of the Keys enumeration consist of a key code and a set of modifiers combined into a single integer value. In the Win32 application programming interface (API) a key value has two halves, with the high-order bits containing the key code (which is the same as a Windows virtual key code), and the low-order bits representing key modifiers such as the SHIFT, CONTROL, and ALT keys.

Converting these constants to **char** is meaningless, since you will lose valuable information and the constant values do not correspond to ASCII character codes.

From [MSDN concerning the **KeyChar** property of **KeyPressEventArgs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx):

> You cannot get or set the following keys (...) INSERT and DELETE (...)

**KeyChar** returns the **char** value (ASCII character code) corresponding to pressed key, not its (raw) key code. Therefore you cannot detect various special keys and cannot compare the value to the **Keys** enumeration constants.

Use the **KeyCode** property of **KeyEventArgs** instead. Since it is of type **Keys**, not **char**, it is well suited for your purpose. In order to access this information, you will have to handle the **KeyDown** event instead of the **KeyPress** event.

By the way, according to the [MSDN page on the **Control** **KeyPress** event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx), this event is not raised for non-character keys at all:

> The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys; however, the noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.

Comment: Thanks for that very precise answer. Still I am wondering why .Net is not consistent in this.

Comment: Actually I think that the **KeyPress** event is just for convenience when all you need is the **char** code. **KeyDown** is triggered before **KeyPress** and is the more generic event.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should compare with `e.KeyCode` instead. It's more precise and you won't need to convert `Keys.Delete` and `Keys.Back` to a `char`.

Comment: The KeyPressEventArgs e doesnt have a property KeyCode (only KeyChar).

I was wondering about this when I wrote the code anyways since the Keys class only has KeyCodes :-/

Comment: That's right, you'd have to use KeyDown instead of KeyPress. I forgot about this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would work in your application to instead capture the KeyDown event.

You could then do something such as:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete || e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
{
   return;
}
```

Note that KeyCode is part of the args passed for KeyDown and KeyUp but not for KeyPress.

Comment: same problem as on Meta-Knights answer. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

KeyPress works with characters, KeyDown works with keys. As both Meta-Knight and itsmatt suggested, you should use KeyDown if you want to detect keys.

If you look at the arithmetic keyboard, you will notice that `Del` and `.` are on the same key.

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you can change the event handler for the control 
//that you are looking at catching the keys.  
//In the example below textBox1 is using 
//setting the KeyEventHandler to be KeyDownEvents Method...  
//this has the KeyCode properties...

this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.KeyDownEvents);
//This is the code in the event...
 private void KeyDownEvents(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete || e.KeyCode == Keys.BrowserBack)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString());
            }
        }
```